# Repairing a Mansfield hosebib

Tags: plumbing

[[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LX5X0S)] sells a kit that claims to replace the rusted-in-place, brittle, plastic insert in this hosebib. However, there's no shutoff in my house except the whole house, so if I try to chip/pry out the old one, and can't install the new one, I'm got to call a plumber as an emergency to cut a hole in a wall to replace the whole thing. What are my chances of success?

[image: a sad hose bib]

Comment: Is that hosebib soldered or threaded on? If it was threaded, you could rush out and buy a cap...

Comment: As far as I know it's soldered inside the wall. It only leaks when it's turned on, so it's not an emergency ... yet.

Comment: In that case, I'd opine that (1) don't do the work on the weekend, and (2) you have a pretty good chance of removing the old plastic -- it's not like you have metal to metal seizing. One risk I can imagine is that the kit won't fit, but you should be able to get a sense of that.